# nvidia: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a problem. I cannot install latest nvidia drivers for my card gt 630, package nvidia-352. I check this the nvidia site and I am sure that driver should compatible with my card. Probably my mainboard is not. Could you please help? google did not help :-( at all

The error message from `dmesg`:

```
[  353.572840] NVRM: The Unknown NVIDIA GT2xx Series GPU installed in this
[  353.572840] NVRM:  system is not supported through the 352.63 NVIDIA
[  353.572840] NVRM:  driver. You can try the NVIDIA 340.xx Legacy drivers.
[  353.572840] NVRM:  Please visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html
[  353.572840] NVRM:  for download information.  The 352.63 NVIDIA driver
[  353.572840] NVRM:  will ignore this GPU.  Continuing probe...
[  353.572877] nvidia: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1
[  353.572901] Error: Driver 'nvlink' is already registered, aborting...
[  353.573313] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
[  353.573315] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!
[  353.573317] [drm] Module unloaded
[  353.573418] NVRM: NVIDIA init module failed!
[  353.574017] systemd-udevd[2755]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  353.574026] systemd-udevd[2755]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
```

Ubuntu version:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

`lspci` output for the card:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 630] [10de:0f00] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
        Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=512M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux vladimir-pc 3.16.0-57-generic #77~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 23:20:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

BIOS information:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 630] [10de:0f00] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
        Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=512M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get install nvidia-340` yet?

Comment: Yes I have tried nvidia -340. But OS does not boot after that. My PC only works if I use nvidia-304 drivers. But I need latest nvidia drivers because I would like to run Dota 2 with Reborn. WIth nvidia-304 dota 2 Reborn got black screen. I found on the Internent that latest drivers help to fix black screen. Reborn it is a new graphic engine. Before steam applied the new engine dota works fine on my PC.

Comment: I'm fetching someone who's better then me to have a look.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the graphics card was not detected properly.
Install the NVIDIA 352 drivers by using a different  method.

First uninstall (possibly partially) installed NVIDIA drivers software.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now Install the drivers 352.63 supporting NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 630.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Note : In case it doesn't work with `nouveau.modeset=0` - retry it with the parameter `nomodeset`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have followed all steps you described but it did not change anything. It does not help. :-(
May be my mainboard not compatible with my nvidia card?

Comment: @АлександрБ : When installing the drivers this way does not work, it is most likely a hardware problem.

Comment: It seems so. Thank you anyway. Is there another way to check if it is a hardware problem?

Comment: @АлександрБ : You're welcome - but before I mislead you, I better say nothing special, because I have no good idea. But sometimes something easy solves problems ... so why not try whether unplugging and re-plugging the NVIDIA graphics card device ... and then try to install the drivers again, does do the trick  ? :)

Comment: No, it does not. Even I have tried use the video card on two different computer. And it does not work anyway. I think to make sure it is a card problem I need Windows. So I will try to find it. And I will try to install nvideo drivers for the card on it.

Comment: Live saver. I somehow kept getting the same message when I tried to access terminal 1 (ctrl + alt + f1), but after a couple of tries it worked. For me `nouveau.modeset=0` worked.