# Ubuntu blank screen after software update 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

I originally had a stretched screen so I updated Nvidia drivers and a system update as well. Then I rebooted and I just got a black screen. Following what what was said from years ago I pressed ‘e’ and changed the grub settings to where specified at the end of the Linux line I typed nomodeset and then F10 to save and start boot.

Now I just have this popping up over and over and over and over again:
[image]

I am not sure what to do at this point since the nomodeset did nothing for me. Any suggestions other than uninstalling and reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch?
[image]

**EDIT:**

What I have tried so far to no success, is launch Ubuntu without installing on a flash drive and uninstalling and then re-installing NVIDIA drivers. I then tried to launch Ubuntu without the flash drive and I get still get a blank black screen.

Any suggestions after this point are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 2:**

The NVIDIA graphics driver that I downloaded was 430. I have a GTX 1070 graphics card.

Comment: [Related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711350/nvidia-probe-of-00000100-0-failed-with-error-1). This seems to 100% be a driver issue, and as @Mark Lwembe has pointed out, this issue was patched in 19.04 & 19.10. So either A) update the drivers, or B) upgrade your operating system

Comment: One of the error messages visible says that '`The NVIDIA GPU installed in this system is not supported`'. Do you know: * What model your GPU is?
* Which version of the 430 driver you used (e.g. 430.9, 430.40)? NVIDIA have listings of supported GPUs for each driver on their website. For example, for [430.40 here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/149138/).

Comment: OK, the 1070 has to be supported still, it's only pretty old models no longer supported. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? How did you go about installing the NVIDIA drivers, with the package manager or directly from NVIDIA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably the new Nvidia driver. If you can't live without it I'd recommend upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10 which I believed corrected bionic's issues concerning this.

Comment: If I upgrade do I lose all the applications and documents I have?

Comment: It's unikely but it's still important to back up your important documents.

Comment: Hi Mark, so do I just download the new Ubuntu 19.10 software onto a flash drive and boot it  up from there and I should be fine?

Comment: Wolfy, while Mark has answered on upgrade and should not impact your home directory after taking precautions, a side note on your worry about a loss of data during complete reinstall ---- in future you may prefer to create one partition for OS image (say 20-40GB) and another large partition for `/home` and mount it. This way, even if you may have to do reinstall, your home directory will remain protected provided that during next install, you reinstall under same OS image partition, and configure it to mount home partition.